# GWTP: event sent once but received (handler) twice

Tags: events, gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

On GWTP I am sending a `UpdateDiagramBoxEvent` with the code below, but the handler is executed twice. In other words, I can see that the `sendUpdateDiagramBoxEvent()` is executed only once, but it is received twice. The same is happening with many other events on my code. Any ideas of what is wrong, and how can I avoid this behaviour? THANKS.

**Receive event**

```
UpdateDiagramBoxHandler updateDiagramBoxHandler = new UpdateDiagramBoxHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onUpdateDiagramBox(UpdateDiagramBoxEvent event) {
    doSomething();
  }
};
```

**Send event**

```
EventUtil.sendUpdateDiagramBoxEvent(CellTableManager.this.eventBus, 
  BasicConstants.EventSubscriptors.VIEW, 0, 
  BasicConstants.EditableTableFields.DIAGRAMTYPE,                                           
  ClientState.getCurrentDiagramType().name());

public static void sendUpdateDiagramBoxEvent(final EventBus eventBus, 
    final BasicConstants.EventSubscriptors recipient, 
    final int index, final BasicConstants.EditableTableFields field, 
    final String value){

    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {    
        @Override
    public void execute() {
      UpdateDiagramBoxEvent updateDiagramBoxEvent = 
        new UpdateDiagramBoxEvent(transactionNumber, recipient, 
            field.toString(), value, index);
        eventBus.fireEvent(updateDiagramBoxEvent);
        }                               
    });
  }
```

**Register event handler (from MyProjectPresenter.java)**

```
@Inject PlaceManager placeManager;
@Override
protected void onBind() {
   [...]                      
       registerHandler(getEventBus().addHandler(UpdateDiagramBoxEvent.getType(),
       updateDiagramBoxHandler));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally means that you simply registered your event handlers twice.

Comment: Just included the "register event handler" code. Seems to be done only once. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be on different instances?

Answer (score 0):

Is this GWTP and if so how are you registering your events/handlers? I seem to recall there is a pitfall that you can use either `@ProxyEvent` *or* `addRegisteredHandler()` but not both, or you will receive the events twice.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks! We are using GWTP, but we are using addRegisteredHandler() only, and seems that it is only called once.

Comment: Just included the "register event handler" code. I see that I am using a different function: registerHandler() from com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.HandlerContainerImpl. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Don't think so, but even so it is usual to use `addRegisteredHandler( UpdateDiagramBoxEvent.getType() , this )` in your presenter.

Answer (score 0):

Or the bean in question might not be singleton.